# Angular: Show/Hide component depending on other component state

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `checkbox` and `textbox` on a web page. `Checkbox` and `Textbox` are two independent components.

Textbox should be hidden till the moment checkbox is on. If checkbox is off - textbox should be hidden

Is it possible via directives ? Something like:

```html
<checkbox></checkbox>
<textbox *ngIf="checkbox.value"></textbox>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just missed to identify the element that you are referring to and using its property.

one of the following two code should work for you:

```
<checkbox ngModel #myCheckbox></checkbox>
<textbox *ngIf="myCheckbox.value"></textbox>



<checkbox ngModel id="myCheckbox"></checkbox>
<textbox *ngIf="myCheckbox.value"></textbox>
```

This link can be useful for you :
[element-refs-in-angular-templates](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/element-refs-in-angular-templates)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `EventEmitter` and `Input`, `Output` in angular for components relations.

like this:

***checkbox-component.html***

```
<checkbox (change)="changeEvent()"></checkbox>
```

***checkbox-component.ts***

```
@Output checkboxChange: Eventemitter<boolean> = new Eventemitter<boolean>();

changeEvent(){
   // if checbox checked value is true else false
   this.checkboxChange.emit(value);
}
```

***parent-component.html***

```
<textbox-component [ShowValue]="checkBoxValue"></textbox-component>
<checkbox-component (checkboxChange)="onCheckboxChange($event)"></checkbox-component>
```

***parent-component.ts***

```
onCheckboxChange(value){
 this.checkBoxValue = value;
}
```

***textbox-component.ts***

```
  @Input() public set ShowValue(value: boolean) 
  {
    this.show = value;
  }
```

***textbox-component.html***

```
<textbox *ngIf="show"></textbox>
```

the parent component is your web page that contains your independent components.

Comment: Thank you, Hasan,  it works but it looks like Habib solution is more elegant